# Passing Entities as method parameters vs sending new object created from part of entity

Tags: java, performance, jpa, parameters, entities

I get a list of `@Entity`es for a query (so called Main Entities). I have to fill some of the Transient fields in these Entities with values from different queries / entities. So each of these transient fields needs different combination of fields from the Main Entities and based on that I should run query and fill the transient fields. These are done in 3 to 4 different methods.

My question is, what is the better approach in terms of performance and practice?

1. Pass Main Entities list (could be in 100s) to each of these methods and get them filled in the method or
2. Create an object based on the fields needed for each method and get the result back and fill the entities?

When you pass the entities to the methods, you are not creating copies, you are just passing original list? No performance related issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for primitive types, every object passed to methods as parameter is passed as reference. Therefore you won't create copies of your entities if you pass a `List<EntityClass>` object to your methods.

If there isn't any other reason not to do so, I would go with option 1 and pass the list of entities to the methods.

Comment: So its better to pass the list of entities rather than creating objects with some fields for each method?

Comment: Regarding performance, yes. Creating 100 objects doesn't cost much, but as far as I understood your question, you would create these objects, let the methods fill them and then merge them back into the entities. That's quite a bit of extra work, if passing the entities themselves would be okay as well.

Comment: Thanks! Are there better ways to do it?